# 2-dimensional array not being updated as expected

Tags: arrays, 2d, output

I'm running the following code on a 4x4 array:

```
private static final int DIMENSION = 4, MAXIMUM = 99;

public static int[][] floydAlgorithm(int[][] oldMatrix)
{
    int[][] newMatrix = new int[oldMatrix.length][oldMatrix[0].length];

    // nested for loops that update the new matrix with the minimum between the
    // old array entry and the sum of two elements along the same row and
    //column of the old array entry
    for (int x = 0; x < oldMatrix.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < oldMatrix[0].length; y++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++)
                newMatrix[x][y] = Math.min(oldMatrix[x][y], 
                        oldMatrix[x][i] + oldMatrix[i][y]);
        }
    }

    return newMatrix;
}

public static void fillFloydMatrix(int[][] matrix) // fills 2d array with values
{
    int [] allInts = {0, 7, 5, MAXIMUM, MAXIMUM, 0, 7, 6,
            MAXIMUM, MAXIMUM, 0, MAXIMUM, 4, 1, 11, 0};

    for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix[0].length; y++)
            matrix[x][y] = allInts[DIMENSION * x + y];
}

public static void displayMatrix(int[][] matrix)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix[0].length; y++)
            System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] floydMatrix = new int[DIMENSION][DIMENSION];

    fillFloydMatrix(floydMatrix);

    displayMatrix(floydMatrix);

    floydMatrix = floydAlgorithm(floydMatrix);

    System.out.println();

    displayMatrix(floydMatrix);
}
```

For some reason, this code outputs the two arrays below, the first of which prints as expected but the second does not:

0, 7, 5, 99

99, 0, 7, 6

99, 99, 0, 99

4, 1, 11, 0

*

0, 7, 5, 99

10, 0, 7, 6

99, 99, 0, 99

4, 1, 11, 0

The 99 on the leftmost column, 2nd row, correctly updates to 10 ([1][3] + [3][0], 6 + 4) but the upper rightmost 99 does not update to 13 ([0][1] + [1][3], 7 + 6) and the 11 at the bottom does not update to 8 ([1][2] + [3][1], 7 + 1). I've tried to find out why but ultimately, I have had no luck in spotting what the issue is. Thus I ask for help in finding the reason why? Thank you so much for your help and time in advance and of course, I will continue to look into why this behavior might be but additional eyes can't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
newMatrix[x][y] = Math.min(oldMatrix[x][y], 
                    oldMatrix[x][i] + oldMatrix[i][y]);
```

with this:

```
newMatrix[x][y] = Math.min(newMatrix[x][y], 
                    oldMatrix[x][i] + oldMatrix[i][y]);
```

You will also need to initialize your new matrix by filling with [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). See [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) .

Comment: I do believe I've tried that in the past but since all newMatrix entries are 0, that would initialize all values to 0 due to Math.min method. I'm stumped.

Comment: This line `for (int y = 0; y < oldMatrix[0].length; y++)` also has to be changed to `for (int y = 0; y < oldMatrix[x].length; y++)`

Comment: Actually, the oldMatrix[0].length is a way to refer to a 2-dimensional array's width. Either way though, the values are the same.

Comment: Let's use the example for the upper rightmost 99 and why didn't it work with your code. There are 4 comparisons performed: 99 with (0 + 99); 99 with (7 + 6); 99 with (5 + 99); and 99 with (99 + 0). The result of each comparison overwrites the result of the previous one, so it's only the last comparison that counts. So the minimum from 99 and (99 + 0) is stored in the new matrix. Got it? :)